# I'm currently working on deploying an API gateway connected to S3

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, yaml, aws-api-gateway, serverless

I'm currently working on deploying an API gateway connected to S3. The primary objective is to send data from the API to S3 using a PUT HTTP request. To achieve this, I'm using the Serverless Framework with a framework version of 3.

```
plugins:  - serverless-apigateway-service-proxy

custom:
  apiGatewayServiceProxies:
     - s3:
         path: /coupons-list
         method: put
         action: PutObject
         bucket: MyS3BucketArn
         cors: true
```

this is the my faild result
TypeError [ERR_INVALID_ARG_TYPE]: The "path" argument must be of type string or an instance of Buffer or URL. Received undefined

Comment: Perhaps wrap `/coupons-list` in quotes?

Comment: Unfortunately, it tried this 2 ways      
  path: /"coupons-list"
        path: "/coupons-list"
and still got the same results..